# Views Arguments Title

Tags: views, 6

I have a view which has an argument passed to it. I provide a default argument of "User ID from URL". I then use `%1's content` in the Title. This returns `username's content`.

I have a content profile associated with a user. I want to get the `field_first_name` from the content profile and display it in the title. So I would get `Lucy's content`. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your argument for configuration
Add validator options for your argument by selecting PHP Code from the select box
Add following code in it

```
 $usr = user_load(array(uid => (int)arg(2))) //Check the appropriate position of uid
 $view->display['page_2']->handler->handlers['argument']['date_argument']->options['title'] = $usr->field_first_name . "'s content";
```

Here `page_2` is views identifier and `date_argument` is argument identifier.